# how do i set property of text box to UpperCase

Tags: html

I use following style attribute so when i will start typing in text box suppose 'railway'then it should get enter in text box like 'RAILWAY'  without pressing CapsLock

```
<input type = "text" class = "normal" name = "Name" size = "20" maxlength = "20"> <img src="../images/tickmark.gif" border="0" style='text-transform:uppercase'/>
```

but I am not getting desired output by using this attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best method would be to change the styling on your form to display uppercase:

```
input.normal
{
   text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

[**SEE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/ULAcb/)

---

However this will not actually convert the string to uppercase, just style it to appear this way.

Therefore then when the data is submitted, use whatever server side language to convert the string to uppercase for purposes of storing in the database etc. For example with .NET you would do:

```
str.ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using CSS, if you only care about stylistic aspect:

```
.normal { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

If you need the text itself to be in all-caps (which is probably what you meant, sorry), combine with a bit of jQuery (it can be done without jQuery, too, but what's the point in that?):

```
$('.normal').change(function() {
   $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/QwSSe/1/

Comment: Its worth noting the value is not actually converted to uppercase however http://stackoverflow.com/a/11099756/370103

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your text transform in your Input tag, not your Image tag. Like this.

```
<input type = "text" class = "normal" name = "Name" style="text-transform:uppercase;" size = "20" maxlength = "20">
<img src="../images/tickmark.gif" border="0"/>
```

Comment: Damn, Ninja'd 3 times within a minute :(

Comment: Its worth noting the value is not actually converted to uppercase however http://stackoverflow.com/a/11099756/370103